# Make C preprocessor Evaluate Best Array Dimension

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I believed this would be trivial to do, but I could not find an answer. Let's consider this setup.

```
// suppose we often change the values of A,B,C
#define A 5
#define B 10
#define C 1
#define SIZE MAX(A+C,B)  //find the max somehow

int array[SIZE]
```

In my program, I have many parameters and complex expressions. I'm trying to figure out a way to find the best value to use to allocate the array without computing it by hand every time.

Comment: What's wrong with the current code? It seems to work (except that you have to define a MAX macro).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the biggest value between `A + B` and `C` you can use a ternary expression in your macro.

Something like:

```
#define A 5
#define B 10
#define C 1

#define MAX(A,B,C) ((((A) + (B)) > (C)) ? ((A) + (B)) : (C))
#define SIZE MAX(A,B,C) //15 the value of A + B
```

```
int array[SIZE];
```

If you have more than 2 values to compare you can chain these to find the maximum value.

Let's say you have a `D` macro you could then do:

```
//...
#define D 20

#define MAX(A,B,C,D) (((((A) + (B)) > C) && (((A) + (B)) > D)) ? ((A) + (B)) : (((C) > (D)) ? (C) : (D)))
#define SIZE MAX(A,B,C,D)  //20 the value of D
```

Answer (score 2):

> In my program, I have many parameters and complex expressions.

**Remember that a C file could be generated** (e.g. by another C program, or a [Python](https://python.org/) script, or a [GNU guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/) script, or some [GPP](https://logological.org/gpp) script, or some [GNU m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/) script, or some [Lua](https://lua.org/) script, or some [GNU gawk](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) script). An example of very useful C code generator is [GNU bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/) (itself coded mostly in C). It generates some parsing routines.

**So you could consider writing or reusing some C code generator**, then configure your [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool (e.g. [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/)) to compile some *generated* C code (which could be `#include`-ed appropriately, if so needed).

See also [GNU autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/). It generates a `configure` script which may compile several generated C files to tune your software to your operating system.

An interesting book describing how generated C code can be useful is J.Pitrat's book [*Artificial Beings: the Conscience of a Conscious Machine*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1848211015) ISBN-13: 978-1848211018.

In my [Bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/) software I am generating C code (e.g. files under the [`modules/`](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/tree/master/modules) subdirectory  ...)

On Linux, you could generate C code, compile it into a plugin, and use it later (in the same process) with [dlopen(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) and [dlsym(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html).

#### Regarding the idea of generating C code, see also [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/257873/40065).